# Explicitly specify an associated type

Tags: swift, associated-types

In the following example, my 'Type' has an 'Option'. And I use them in a Field struct by insuring that they are coherent thanks to the where clause in the Generics part.

```
protocol Type {
    associatedtype O: Option
    var typeOption: O? { get }
}

protocol Option {

}

struct Field<T: Type, O: Option where T.O == O> {
    let type: T
    let option: O
}
```

It works fine. But the typeOption property is useless. In fact I put it only so the type of the Option can be inferred as with the String's extension example.

```
struct StringOption: Option {

}

extension String: Type {    
    var typeOption: StringOption? {
        return nil
    }    
}
```

So my question is, can I get rid of this useless property or, in other words, can I explicitly specify the associated type?

Comment: How do you want to use it? It seems backwards to me that a Type would know about its Option.

Comment: My main use is the Field example, to insure that the type property has a appropriate option property. So in a way, I'm using this information outside of the 'Type'.